# Update one Field based on another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

As a part of my form I have a field for selecting items and a button which the client clicks in order to add the items to their list of units. I wish to show the list of units selected by the user in the units text field. How do I implement the onclick function for the button so that it takes the currently selected value for the select component before appending it to the list as presented by the textbox? I have a separate save button which will take the form data and send it to the backend when clicked.

```
let EditUserForm = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit, units } = props;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

            <Field name="units" component="input" type="text" readOnly/> 

            <Field name="unit" component="select" >
            {
                units.map(u => <option value={u} key={u}>{u}</option>)
            }
            </Field>

            <button type="button" onClick={props.updateUserUnits}>Add unit</button>

        </form>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do something like in the code below. This combines several `redux-form` concepts.

Basically you want to intercept the `onChange` event from the `select` component, so you can attach some logic to it.

In this case we'll use the `change` prop that is passed down by `redux-form`. This will allow you to change the value of another field in the form.

Combine this with the `formValueSelector` which allows you to get a value from a specific form field.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Field, FieldArray, formValueSelector, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const EditUser = (props) => {
    const { change, handleSubmit, selectedUnits = [], units } = props;

    const handleUnitChange = (event, value) => {
      const newUnits = [ ...selectedUnits, value ];

      change('units', newUnits);
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field name="units" component="input" type="text" readOnly/> 

            <Field name="unit" component="select" onChange={handleUnitChange}>
              {units.map(u => <option value={u} key={u}>{u}</option>)}
            </Field>

            <button type="button" onClick={props.sendData}>Add unit</button>
        </form>
    );
};

const form = 'editUserForm';

const EditUserForm = reduxForm({
  form
})(EditUser);

const selector = formValueSelector(form);

export default connect(state => ({
  selectedUnits: selector(state, 'units')
}))(EditUserForm);
```

Comment: NOTE: the `change` from **redux-form** it's the function that does the trick